# Intermittent but frequent problems attempting to connect to a Windows share from El Capitan (Mac OS X)

Tags: networking, macos, mac, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials machine with a share.  The share is configured to allow anybody to connect without authentication.

From a Terminal session in El Capitan repeated attempts to connect to the share fail (these are the actual commands - there is no redacted password):

```
Michaels-Mac:MugShooter mbmast$ mount_smbfs //guest@mteserver/Share ~/sharename
mount_smbfs: server connection failed: Socket is not connected
Michaels-Mac:MugShooter mbmast$ mount_smbfs //guest@mteserver/Share ~/sharename
mount_smbfs: server connection failed: Socket is not connected
Michaels-Mac:MugShooter mbmast$ mount_smbfs //guest@mteserver/Share ~/sharename
mount_smbfs: server connection failed: Socket is not connected
Michaels-Mac:MugShooter mbmast$ mount_smbfs //guest@mteserver/Share ~/sharename
mount_smbfs: server connection failed: Socket is not connected
Michaels-Mac:MugShooter mbmast$ mount_smbfs //guest@mteserver/Share ~/sharename
mount_smbfs: server connection failed: Socket is not connected
```

And doing a `df` proves there is no connection:

```
Michaels-Mac:MugShooter mbmast$ df
Filesystem     512-blocks      Used Available Capacity  iused   ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2    124149904 110642456  12995448    90% 13894305 1624431   90%   /
devfs                 370       370         0   100%      641       0  100%   /dev
map -hosts              0         0         0   100%        0       0  100%   /net
map auto_home           0         0         0   100%        0       0  100%   /home
/dev/disk1s0s2       5800      5800         0   100%     1448       0  100%   /Volumes/VMware Tools
/dev/disk2s1      8042488    515304   7527184     7%        0       0  100%   /Volumes/NO NAME
```

Then, suddenly, it it works with no error:

```
Michaels-Mac:MugShooter mbmast$ mount_smbfs //guest@mteserver/Share ~/sharename
```

And doing another `df` shows that it worked:

```
Michaels-Mac:MugShooter mbmast$ df
Filesystem               512-blocks       Used Available Capacity   iused    ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2              124149904  110641840  12996064    90%  13894228  1624508   90%   /
devfs                           370        370         0   100%       642        0  100%   /dev
map -hosts                        0          0         0   100%         0        0  100%   /net
map auto_home                     0          0         0   100%         0        0  100%   /home
/dev/disk1s0s2                 5800       5800         0   100%      1448        0  100%   /Volumes/VMware Tools
/dev/disk2s1                8042488     515304   7527184     7%         0        0  100%   /Volumes/NO NAME
//guest:@mteserver/Share 3905742840 3495200056 410542784    90% 436900005 51317848   89%   /Users/mbmast/sharename
```

Then a few seconds later...

```
Michaels-Mac:MugShooter mbmast$ df
Filesystem     512-blocks      Used Available Capacity  iused   ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2    124149904 110642968  12994936    90% 13894369 1624367   90%   /
devfs                 370       370         0   100%      642       0  100%   /dev
map -hosts              0         0         0   100%        0       0  100%   /net
map auto_home           0         0         0   100%        0       0  100%   /home
/dev/disk1s0s2       5800      5800         0   100%     1448       0  100%   /Volumes/VMware Tools
/dev/disk2s1      8042488    515304   7527184     7%        0       0  100%   /Volumes/NO NAME
```

It's gone.  So I have two questions:

1. Why do I get so many **Socket is not connected** errors, but then it just works with no error?
2. Why are the connections so short lived (a few seconds, a minute maybe)?  While I have the connection, I can see all the files in the share (which I did not include here), I can access those files and I can move files from the share to the Mac and from the Mac to the share.

Also... El Capitan is running in a VMware Workstation VM on the Windows Server machine (i.e. both are running on the same physical box), so I don't see how my problem could be related to network infrastructure (router, cable, NIC, etc.).  The VM (running El Capitan) has a bridged network connection (i.e. I'm not using NAT).

Comment: This is starting to look like an El Capitan issue.  I upgraded the VM to Siera and I am not having this problem... so far.  Will update in a few days after more extensive testing.

Answer (score 0):

The server I was attempting to connect to from El Capitan was assigned a static IP address.  It turns out there was a wireless access point on the network with the same static IP address.  I now believe this was the root cause of the connection problems.